# Saving catplot subfigures into a single figure file

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization, catplot

I need to combine catplot subfigures into a single figure and then save that figure to a file. I used `plt.subplots` to create independent axis for each subfigure and then assigned the catplots to the subfigures. The figure looks fine in a Jupyter notebook (see [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jdHe9h9jqOcIowZaTG4BZ5KlLCu85Pgl/view?usp=sharing)), but when I check the stored file I see a blank figure with two subplots (see [blank figure](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U_F99RkKf0libZwNEKTnOOdGU1dfWZok/view?usp=sharing)). I reviewed related posts (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56788245/is-there-a-restriction-on-catplot-with-subplot) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65822467/plotting-two-seaborn-catplots-in-one-figure)), but their focus is not in storing the produced figure. I wonder what I can do store a single file with the figure containing both catplot subfigures. Please see my reproducible code below along with datasets here ([df1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nZVOMtDWOV9C-NdrJeCtIzj5ZUGfmCdQ/view?usp=sharing) and [df2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1taAWYdl9e2Lt-HiXqxTzIYec7KqjkxOe/view?usp=sharing)). I used `pandas` version 1.2.3, `matplotlib` version 3.3.4, and `seaborn` version 0.11.0.

Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Read data
df1 = pd.read_csv("df1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("df2.csv")

# Setup subfigures
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(10, 7))
category_order = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

# Top subfigure
g = sns.catplot(x="Month", hue="Day of Week", kind="count", data=df1, hue_order=category_order, legend=False, aspect=20/8, ax=axs[0])

# Annotate bars
ax[0] = g.facet_axis(0, 0)
for p in ax[0].patches:
    ax[0].text(p.get_x(), 
            p.get_height()*1.02, 
            f"{p.get_height():.0f}", 
            color="black", 
            rotation="horizontal", 
            size="small")

# Formatting
g.tight_layout()
g.set(ylim=(0, 18))
sns.despine(ax=ax[0], top=False, right=False)    
    
# Bottom subfigure    
g = sns.catplot(x="Month", hue="Day of Week", kind="count", data=df2, hue_order=category_order, legend=True, aspect=20/8, ax=axs[1])

# Annotate bars
ax[1] = g.facet_axis(0, 0)
for p in ax[1].patches:
    ax[1].text(p.get_x(), 
            p.get_height()*1.02, 
            f"{p.get_height():.0f}", 
            color="black", 
            rotation="horizontal", 
            size="small")

# Formatting    
g.tight_layout()
g.set(ylim=(0, 18))
sns.despine(ax=ax[1], top=False, right=False)
g.set_xlabels("Date")

# Close blank figure
plt.close(1)

fig.savefig("fig.pdf", dpi=200, bbox_inches="tight")

plt.show()
```

Comment: If you want multiple sets of data plotted in the same figure, then add a new column to each of the dataframe with the value being a unique identifier, combine the dataframes, and then use the new column as `row=`

Comment: See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd6Ap.png)

Comment: Thanks @TrentonMcKinney. Your code works.